# Generate a string from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, dot

I am trying to generate a dot file based on the string array.

```
edges =[["Source1" ,"interfaceA" , "high" , "Sink1" , "interfaceB" , "high"], 
        ["Source2" ,"interfaceC" , "high" , "Sink2" , "interfaceD" , "low"]]
```

I want my output dot file data to look like :

```
digraph mydot {
    "Source1" -> "Sink1"
    [
       label=<<font color="green">interfaceA</font>--&gt;<font color="green">interfaceB</font>>
    ];
    "Source2" -> "Sink2"
    [
       label=<<font color="green">interfaceC</font>--&gt;<font color="red">interfaceD</font>>
    ];
}
```

I tried the below code but returns something like digraph unnamed {,,}

```
        let mydot ='digraph mydot {  ';
         mydot += edges.map(edge => {
           let sourceInterfaceColor = "red";
           let sinkInterfaceColor = "red";
        if (edge[2]=="high")
          sourceInterfaceColor ="green";
        if(edge[5]=="high")
          sinkInterfaceColor ="green";

        mydot +=`\
                        ${edge[0]} -> ${edge[3]} \
            [                                    \
               label=<<font color= \"${sourceInterfaceColor}\">\"${edge[1]}\"</font>--&gt;<font color=\"${sinkInterfaceColor}\">${edge[4]}</font>> \
            ];`
            .stripMargin});
        mydot +='}';
```

What would be the right way to define mydot to get the correct digraph data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a straightforward way to achieve your desired output. Generally, [template literals enable multiline features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const edges =[["Source1" ,"interfaceA" , "high" , "Sink1" , "interfaceB" , "high"], ["Source2" ,"interfaceC" , "high" , "Sink2" , "interfaceD" , "low"]]

const edgeToString = edge => `
    "${edge[0]}" -> "${edge[3]}"
    [
       label=<<font color="green">${edge[1]}</font>--&gt;<font color="green">${edge[4]}</font>>
    ]
`.trimEnd()

const digraphToString = edges => `digraph mydot {${edges.map(edgeToString).join('')}\n}`

console.log(digraphToString(edges))
```

Comment: But, I want to pass in the edge[2] and edge[5], to decide if color ="green" or "red" based of interface value "high" or "low" ,instead of hardcoding it to be "green" always.
Is it possible to define a var sourceInterfaceColor and sinkInterfaceColor?